# Simple way to change the Colors of a stylebook in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm searching for a simple way to change tho whole Color-Style of a FireMonkey App to match the corporate identity guidlines.
When I get it right, behind every Element in the Stylebook there is a Bitmap and the elements point to the different coordinates.
Questions to that Topic:

1.) Is there a let's call it "parent-Bitmap" where every Element is shown?

2.) How can I save and reload that Bitmap into the Stylebook?

Thanks for Help